# need of a separate database

Tags: database, web

I am working on my first web project. I have referenced many tutorials and pdfs but all those had simple examples for the login and sign-up feature for a webpage, which only used a single database. I am having a massive confusion on whether or not, the login and sign-up should have separate databases.

My main question is : The project intakes user's personal information(name, email, address, telephone number, etc.) along with information specific to their vehicles (model, company, make, manufacture date, etc.). And after logging into the website, both these data's are important but only some of them are in use like, the user's name, his/her address, the model of vehicle, and the company. So should I maintain separate databases for both of them and reference each element with a foreign key while working on databases ?? Or should i just bother less and use a single database and complete my login and sign-up function ??, because with the no. of columns that I have apparently is very large.

Comment: By "database" did you mean "table"?

Comment: I think you actually mean `TABLE` when you say `DATABASE`. And the answer is YES you should use seperate `TABLES` but not seperate `DATABASES'

Comment: it's terrible to separate data into two databases. because DB systems doesn't have any special(well) approach for connecting and linking databases with each other, just one db is enough

Comment: @ViliamBúr, yes I meant separate tables rather than separate databases.

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes I did mean database. So is it a good idea to separate the user's personal information and their vehicle information?

Comment: I would say a definite yes to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a bit too academic, but a word you'll want to learn well is *normalization*. Here is a link to a pretty stiff definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

This being your first web project, my advice would the following:

1. Don't be afraid to make mistakes. I would strongly encourage trying approaches you think are good and then don't be afraid to change your mind. The lessons learned will stick with you.
2. Keep everything simple up front. Only add complexity when you need it.
3. Definitely don't be afraid to grow horizontally with tables (add more and more tables). When I first started working with databases I was afraid to have too many tables because it *felt* wrong. Try to resist the temptation to cram everything in one table.
4. Definitely separate login, users and vehicle information. Not a bad idea to also separate out user address information since people can have more than one address.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the same database for holding all the information for your project. Two different database is not really good idea , you can create many tables in an database. and each table is designed to hold different information.In case of your example you may choose the following tables in the same database

- UserLogin [store login information]
- User [ store personal info]
- Vehicle
- and so on

There must be one to one relationship between UserLogin and User table and one to many in user - Vehicle table 
One user may have many Vehicle

Hopefully it will help

Comment: While I firmly agree that you definitely want multiple tables, I can't upvote this answer because of the statement "You must use the same database for holding all the information for your project." I may want to separate out my high volume data into a separate database (perhaps not even an SQL database), but keep other data (logins, etc) in a different database. This also lets me have different backup, HA strategies etc for the different types of data I'm going to be storing. "One database fits all" works at small scale, but not at enterprise scale.